# Sending the Vendor specific information(code) from dhclient during dhcp discovery

Tags: udhcpc

I am trying to send the vendor specific information(option43 and sub options) during the DHCP discovery using dhcpc.
I Have tried the below option
exec udhcpc -f -V $vendorIdentifier -C 01:$mac -i mPlaneVlan -t $retries -T $timeout -s /etc/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/dhclient_Hook_Wrapper -x OPT43 "\002\004ESTB\003\008ECM:ESTB\004\014$SERIAL_NO\005\013HW_VER1.0.0\006\013FW_VER1.0.0\007\016Boot_ROM25.008\008\006001320\010\015MODEL_NO_3100\011\013VENDOR NAME\066\0100A859B428"

But it is failing saying that there is no OPT43.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! It is fairly hard to answer this question since you haven't provided any of the relevant code. Also please don't paste images. Paste it as text and format it correctly!

Comment: Hi I am looking for the way on how to pass the vendir-specific-information(option43) with sub options. For this i just started the kea-dhcp server with the command "kea-dhcp4 -d -c /tmp/kea-dhcp.conf". After this i am starting the dhcp-client with the vendor-specific-information option43. "\002\004ESTB\003\008ECM:ESTB\004\014$SERIAL_NO\005\013HW_VER1.0.0\006\013FW_VER1.0.0\007\016Boot_ROM25.008\008\006001320\010\015MODEL_NO_3100\011\013VENDOR NAME\066\0100A859B428"